# Drawing conclusions about 3d truss from 2d model

Tags: structural-engineering, statics

I am on the task of analysing the load capacity of a warren-ish truss bridge similar to [this one](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2F736x%2F7f%2Ff1%2Fa1%2F7ff1a1719eadfdc3567338d9b659284b.jpg&f=1). I do not, however, have the software or skill to model and analyse a 3D structure.

I was wondering wether or not i could analyse a [2D](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathalino.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Freviewer-mechanics%2F418-warren-truss.gif&f=1) simplification and still come to a somewhat credible conclusion. What considerations should be made when approximating a 3D truss as a 2D truss? What would be the limitations of such an approach? Thank you.

**Edit:**
I do not have to know the exact maximum load. My only goal is to figure out where the truss will fail first.

Comment: Do you know any of the loads? You can start breaking it down mathematically if you have some knowns.

Comment: Think about what you are getting from the 3D model. You are getting bracing for the top and bottom members.  None of that affects the 2D truss other than knowing that it is there.  Wind or other lateral loads can usually be analyzed separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question "whether or not I could analyse a 2D simplification and still come to a somewhat credible conclusion" is obviously **yes**. After all, how do you think engineers calculated complex structures before the advent of the computer?

The real question, of course, is how to do this **well**.

The first question is how to determine the loading applied to the truss. Each of the trusses must obviously support its own self-weight. The division of the remaining loads among the trusses, however, is a bit more circumstantial.

A reasonable first hypothesis would be to get the total load and divide it evenly between both trusses. If the structure is transversally symmetrical (that is, there is nothing that'd draw more loads to one truss than the other), then that is a perfectly valid assumption for all the dead loads (paving, etc).

For the live loads, however, a bit more care may be required if discrete moving loads are considered. If a car is driving along your bridge, will it be perfectly centered (or close enough)? Then sure, divide the live load evenly between both trusses. Otherwise, if (for example) the bridge is wide enough that the car may be closer to one truss than the other, then more of the live load will go to the near truss. Assuming a transversally symmetric bridge, if the live load will be at a distance $a$ from one truss and $b$ from the other, and $a>b$, then the closer truss will have to withstand a fraction $\dfrac{a}{a+b}$ of the total live load. Obviously, if you're just considering uniformly distributed live loads, then the worst case scenario is to load the entire bridge and divide it evenly between both sides (assuming a transversally symmetric bridge).

Once you know the loads, you can then move on to checking the trusses themselves. Trusses are composed of members that are either in tension or compression. For those in tension, the 3D reality of the structure is irrelevant. For those in compression, it is very relevant. That is because compression can lead to buckling, and so we need to know how the members are braced. If we were dealing with a real 2D truss, the upper chord (under compression) would have no out-of-plane bracing, meaning its effective length would be equal to almost the entire span of the bridge, dramatically reducing its buckling strength. However, we aren't dealing with a 2D truss, but a 3D bridge. And the 3D reality of the truss is that the transversal bracing is restraining the out-of-plane displacement of all the nodes. This has absolutely no effect on the structural analysis calculation of the 2D truss (calculating the internal forces of each member), but it is essential when calculating the truss' design strength.

There are other issues such as wind and other non-vertical loads, but I have a feeling that these are out-of-scope for your question, so I'll leave them out of this answer. Let me know in a comment if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the loads applied to it. If there are only vertical loads (or the lateral loads are insignificant in comparison) then of you can assume each side to behave in similar manner to a 2D truss. Of course you have to consider that the vertical loads in such a bridge reach to the side trusses through bending of the transverse members, so you must consider the possibility of failure of these members too. Furthermore even if you analyse each truss as a 2D structure you should propably consider the presence of the the transverse members when you calculate the resistances of the truss, for lateral buckling failure.

In other circumstances, such as when severe lateral loads exist, or the dynamic response is wanted (which is typical true for bridges) then 3D modeling is required.